# Does a <link rel="stylesheet">` with a non-matching media value download sync or async, render-blocking or non-render-blocking?

Tags: css, rel, render, media

I'm looking for an authoritative reference with regard to whether `<link rel="stylesheet">` with a *non-matching* media attribute value downloads **synchronously** or **render-blocking** or **neither**.

**MDN** helpfully draws attention to Scott Jehl's experiments from several years ago:

> *A style sheet with a media query attached to its  tag will still download even if the query*
> *returns false.*
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
>
> **Additional Reference:** http://scottjehl.github.io/CSS-Download-Tests/

So far, so good.

But is that *download-which-is-happening-anyway*:

- **synchronous** or **asynchronous** ?
- **render-blocking** or **non-render-blocking** ?

I'm going to guess that it's **asynchronous**, **non-render-blocking** and **low priority**.

But I'd really like to confirm this via an authoritative source - and I've been unable to find one.

---

#### Background to this question:

Now that **Firefox** (as of **Jan 2021**) supports `<link rel="preload">` (see: https://caniuse.com/link-rel-preload), I've been running some experiments to see whether I am happiest with the behaviour of:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/my-non-critical-styles.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet';" />
```

versus:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/my-non-critical-styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all';">
```

I can see that they **do behave differently** - a speed/performance tool like [GTMetrix](https://www.gtmetrix.com/) shows very clearly that the `rel="preload"` approach prioritises loading the non-critical stylesheet over images, while the `media="print"` approach prioritises loading images over the non-critical stylesheet - but I also want to be certain that the two approaches are alike in all other respects.

Comment: I've found something here: https://filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html. Scott Jehl (again) states: _"Browsers will consider stylesheets for inapplicable media to be **low-priority**, and download them **without blocking page rendering**."_ If I can't find anything better, I guess that's the confirmation I'm looking for, but it would be nice to see something from W3C, WHAT-WG, WICG, MDN etc.

Comment: See also (albeit, from a different third-party website): _"**When the “print” value is selected for the media attribute**, the browser loads the relevant CSS file **asynchronously**."_ in https://holisticseo.digital/pagespeed/async-css

Comment: Scott Jehl (again): _"[...] by declaring a **media type that doesn’t match** the current environment, we can achieve an interesting and useful effect: the browser will load the stylesheet **without delaying page rendering, asynchronously** [...]"_ in https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/load-css-simpler/

Comment: https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/ and https://web.dev/priority-hints/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/should-css-always-precede-javascript